# opencv_world linking issue

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015, linker

I have an issue linking the provided `opencv_world340.lib` file to my application:

I downloaded the windows prebuilt version of Opencv 3.4.0 from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/3.4.0/opencv-3.4.0-vc14_vc15.exe/download). I linked the opencv_world340.lib to my application with headers and runtime dll from the build\x64\vc14 folder to my Visual Studio 2015 C++ console application.

I am able to create a `cv::Mat` from file, it is well created in runtime, but when I try to convert it with `.convertTo()` (or use any further functionality of OpenCV) I got a LNK2019 linking issue that the function is not resolved. I though the `opencv_world340.lib` is a *all_in_one* file containing every module.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you telling VS to search for libs in `build\x64\vc14\lib`? Is your project a x64? Are you in debug? Because you'll need `opencv_world340d.lib` then

Comment: Lib: Yes

x64: Yes

Debug: Yes -> Indeed this was the problem. Thanks for pointing it out.

I don't really understand the reason though, I already used release lib in debug application.

Comment: glad it helpd. I closed as dupe of another question with the same solution. When there is memory management involved, you'd better use the correct build. For more details on this you can ask a new question (unrelated to OpenCV)